# Differences between Dirichlet boundary conditions in the case of acoustic waves and electric potentials?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, waves, acoustics, boundary-conditions

If we have a an acoustic wave $u$ governed by the Helmholtz equation on the interval $[0, 1]$ then a Dirichlet boundary condition $$u(x) |_{x = 1} = 0,$$
means that the wave goes becomes zero at the boundary $x=1$ and reflects back in the opposite direction.

If we have an electric potential $\phi$ governed by the Laplace equation on the interval $[0, 1]$ then what does a Dirichlet boundary condition $$\phi(x) |_{x=1} = 0,$$
mean in this case? We don't have a wave? So there is nothing to 'reflect'?

So what are the differences in these Dirichlet boundary conditions when one is for acoustic waves and the other is for electric potentials?

Comment: The Helmholtz equation is a time-independent form of the wave equation.  Laplace's equation is just a limit of Poisson's equation in steady-state.  The equations for which the functions $u$ and $\phi$ are solutions are the primary difference here, not the boundary conditions.

Comment: Single Dirichlet boundary conditions aren't sufficient for a full solution of these PDEs. At least another Dirichlet or possibly another type of boundary condition is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Helmholtz, e.g. in two dimensions:**

$$u_{xx}+u_{yy}=-\lambda^2u$$
Ansatz:
$$W(x,y)=X(x)Y(y)$$
Separation of variables:
$$YX''+XY''=-\lambda^2XY$$
$$\frac{X''}{X}+\frac{Y''}{Y}=-\lambda^2$$
$$\frac{X''}{X}=-\lambda^2-\frac{Y''}{Y}=-k^2$$
$$X''+k^2X=0$$
$$X(x)=c_1\cos kx+c_2\sin kx$$
Dirichlet boundary condition:

$$u(1,y)=0\implies X(1)=0$$
$$X(1)=c_1\cos k+c_2\sin k=0$$

**2. Laplace, e.g. in two dimensions:**

$$\phi_{xx}+\phi_{yy}=0$$
$$\phi(x,y)=X(x)Y(y)$$
$$\frac{X''}{X}=-\frac{Y''}{Y}=-k^2$$
$$X''+k^2X=0$$
$$X(x)=c_1\cos kx+c_2\sin kx$$
Dirichlet boundary condition:

$$u(1,y)=0\implies X(1)=0$$
$$X(1)=c_1\cos k+c_2\sin k=0$$

**In both cases**, unless combined with another Dirichlet boundary condition like $u(0,y)=0$ or $\phi(0,y)=0$, the OP given Dirichlets aren't particularly useful. Combined with the boundary conditions, i.e. $u(0,y)=0$ or $\phi(0,y)=0$, the $k$ values (eigenvalues) can be determined.

The solutions in both cases are of the *standing waves* type.